# Guide to open data for beginners

Tags: data-request, data-portal

Is there a guide or an introduction of some sorts to open data, indicating to a beginner how and where he or she should go about trying to find interesting datasets?

Comment: beginner in using or publishing open data?

Answer (score 5):

Open Data looks a bit like a jungle at first but you'll find tons of awesome data and tons of ideas to create stuff with it!

The first questions would be: are you searching some particuliar data or are you just curious? what do you want to do with those data?

Then I would say:

1. the first step is find some data near you. The [OKFN](https://okfn.org/) runs a service called [Data Portals](http://dataportals.org/) where you'll be able to find your government/city open data portal ([eg. City of Paris, France](http://opendata.paris.fr/page/home/)). Usualy data are in CSV/TSV, XLS so you can explore them with a [Spreadsheet Software](https://www.libreoffice.org/).
2. you can check plenty of other sources with thousands of open data websites: [OpenDataSites](http://data.okfn.org/data/okfn/opendatasites) or this [Quora Q&A](http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public).
3. then you will probably want to do something with those data. Depending of your skills, time, and what you want you can try some data science library like [R](https://www.r-project.org/) or [Python](http://radimrehurek.com/data_science_python/), some data visualization (personnaly I like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)), some map creation (I heard that [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) was cool but I've never tested it).
4. the next step will probably be some global data like data from [the UN](https://data.un.org/) or the [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/). It will be a good lesson on how it can be difficult to access some data even if they are open :)
5. you'll search some data for hours, ending here to ask the community
6. you'll find out that even if there are more and more open data, there are still a lot of data difficult to find and not open. That will be a good time to first learn more about scrapping (eg. with [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) but every language has its library or with stuff like [Import.io](https://import.io/)), and second, make friend with people, NGOs, companies that are fighting/working on making Open Data bigger and bigger. You'll easily find those people/org online ;)
7. finally you'll probably want to be curious about stuff like [Semantic Web and Linked Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data).

Then, I hope you will have seen the huge power Open Data gives to people and if you work at a company/organisation that has some interresting data you'll wonder how to open them easily. There will be a lot of informations online, some guides too. Some ready-to-go platforms exists, some [Open Source](http://ckan.org/), some not like [Socrata](http://www.socrata.com/) or [OpenDataSoft](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/) (DISCLAIMER: I work for the latter) and plenty of others.

I hope it'll help you. Don't forget that your favorite search engine will be a direct access to the data you want in most cases.